# Publishing a Google Docs Add on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I have built a Google Script which is currently bound to my present Google docs document. It is a simple script that has a menu item and a Sidebar. I wish to access it from all my google docs document. I think the way to do it is publishing it on the Chrome Web Store as an add-on. It requires a developer fee of $5 which I have no problem paying but I want my script to be private(or shareable only to selected few) because it contains my API key that I don't want to share.

1. Please let me know if there is any alternative except publishing it as an add-on
2. If I publish it, can I use it privately and not share it. if that is true then how to do it.
3. If there is totally another way to do this, I'm all ears.

Sorry if that is a trivial question, I am a complete beginner.

P.S. I read a few answers saying it can be done but from my knowledge Google has updated the conditions, so wanted to verify before giving the developer fee

Comment: You could use a library.  That is the alternative.  Using a library avoids the need for setting up and publishing an add-on.  So, a library is much easier in that sense.  A library is viewable only to any account who you have shared the Apps Script file with.  So, it's private by default if you haven't shared the script file with anyone.  A library can be deployed with the Apps Script API.  That's not easy, but there is an option to deploy the library to your files through code.

Comment: Would the triggers(OnOpen,OnInstall) work with libraries. My motive is to get a menu item permanently/OnOpen in all my Docs documents. I don't think library would be a solution for that. Correct me if I am wrong. Appreciate the help!

Comment: Simple triggers like `onOpen()` can not be triggered from within a library.  So, you'd need a way to put code into the script.  You could copy and paste.  You could copy Sheet files with a bound script.  But if you already have multiple sheets, then copying Sheet templates probably won't help you.  So, installing an add-on is probably easier than those alternatives.  You need to provide images to the add-on set up, which is work, but you can just throw anything in there as long as it's the correct dimension.

Comment: That's what I had figured till now. But as mentioned in the question I need to confirm if I can publish my add on privately. I have my API key in the add on and for obvious reasons I don't want to share that.

Comment: Yes, you can publish the add-on privately.